# How to make single listbox in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components

lightning:dualListbox has re-orderble listbox, but I couldn't find re-orderble  **single** listbox.

How can I get this, or there is nothing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SLDS [Listbox Pattern](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/accessibility/patterns/listbox/#site-main-content) describes how such a list should function, but there is no specific component that uses this design. You can write your own listbox using the SLDS-provided instructions. Presumably, if you have enough development skills to have a need for such a component, it should be pretty easy to write one. I'd estimate probably 100-150 lines of code to include support for drag-and-drop features, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I think <li/> doesn't accept using valiable as its items. I want to get my object and make list by it. Is this solvable?

Comment: I built a custom dualListbox https://github.com/rapsacnz/DualSelect. The cool thing ( I think) is that this dualListbox is build using.... two Listboxes that I called Ordered Lists: https://github.com/rapsacnz/DualSelect/tree/master/src/aura/OrderedList They are designed to work independently.